# ErrNo 0 and Error empty but not completing

Tags: php, mysql

I was hoping someone could lend a second set of eyes...  My code is returning ErrNo 0 and Error (empty) but not completing...  It could be something with one of the vars because when I reduce it to just adding one column it seems to work...  Just not sure if maybe because of $S07SS01Q14 being a checkbox that it is causing the error or if the checkbox is in there correct...

(sorry for the length of the code)

```
$link = mysqli_connect('hostname', 'username', 'mypw'); 
if (!$link) { 
 die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error()); 
}  
mysqli_select_db($link,'tbl1'); 

$username = $_POST['username'];
$tenureyears = $_POST['tenureYears'];
$tenuremonths = $_POST['tenureMonths'];
$gender = $_POST['gender']; 
$marital = $_POST['marital'];

$S01SS01Q01 = $_POST['S01SS01Q01'];
$S01SS01Q01TB = $_POST['S01SS01Q01TB'];
$S01SS01Q02 = $_POST['S01SS01Q02'];
$S01SS01Q02TB = $_POST['S01SS01Q02TB'];
$S01SS01Q03 = $_POST['S01SS01Q03'];
$S01SS01Q03TB = $_POST['S01SS01Q03TB'];
$S01SS01Q04 = $_POST['S01SS01Q04'];
$S01SS01Q04TB = $_POST['S01SS01Q04TB'];
$S01SS01Q05 = $_POST['S01SS01Q05'];
$S01SS01Q05TB = $_POST['S01SS01Q05TB'];
$S01SS01Q06 = $_POST['S01SS01Q06'];
$S01SS01Q06TB = $_POST['S01SS01Q06TB'];
$S01SS01Q07 = $_POST['S01SS01Q07'];

$S02SS01Q01 = $_POST['S02SS01Q01'];
$S02SS01Q02 = $_POST['S02SS01Q02'];
$S02SS01Q03 = $_POST['S02SS01Q03'];
$S02SS01Q04 = $_POST['S02SS01Q04'];;
$S02SS01Q05 = $_POST['S02SS01Q05'];
$S02SS01Q06 = $_POST['S02SS01Q06'];
$S02SS01Q07 = $_POST['S02SS01Q07'];
$S02SS01Q08 = $_POST['S02SS01Q08'];
$S02SS01Q09 = $_POST['S02SS01Q09'];
$S02SS01Q10 = $_POST['S02SS01Q10'];
$S02SS01Q11 = $_POST['S02SS01Q11'];
$S02SS01TB = $_POST['S02SS01TB'];

$S03SS01Q01 = $_POST['S03SS01Q01'];
$S03SS01Q02 = $_POST['S03SS01Q02'];
$S03SS01Q03 = $_POST['S03SS01Q03'];
$S03SS01Q04 = $_POST['S03SS01Q04'];
$S03SS01Q05 = $_POST['S03SS01Q05'];
$S03SS01Q06 = $_POST['S03SS01Q06'];
$S03SS01Q07 = $_POST['S03SS01Q07'];
$S03SS01Q08 = $_POST['S03SS01Q08'];
$S03SS01Q09 = $_POST['S03SS01Q09'];
$S03SS01Q10 = $_POST['S03SS01Q10'];
$S03SS01Q11 = $_POST['S03SS01Q11'];
$S03SS01Q12 = $_POST['S03SS01Q12'];
$S03SS01Q13 = $_POST['S03SS01Q13'];
$S03SS01Q14 = $_POST['S03SS01Q14'];
$S03SS01Q15 = $_POST['S03SS01Q15'];
$S03SS01Q16 = $_POST['S03SS01Q16'];
$S03SS01TB = $_POST['S03SS01TB'];

$S04SS01Q01 = $_POST['S04SS01Q01'];
$S04SS01Q01TB = $_POST['S04SS01Q01TB'];
$S04SS01Q02 = $_POST['S04SS01Q02'];
$S04SS01Q02TB = $_POST['S04SS01Q02TB'];
$S04SS01Q03 = $_POST['S04SS01Q03'];
$S04SS01Q03TB = $_POST['S04SS01Q03TB'];
$S04SS01Q04 = $_POST['S04SS01Q04'];
$S04SS01Q04TB = $_POST['S04SS01Q04TB'];
$S04SS01Q05 = $_POST['S04SS01Q05'];
$S04SS01Q05TB = $_POST['S04SS01Q05TB'];
$S04SS01Q06 = $_POST['S04SS01Q06'];
$S04SS01Q06TB = $_POST['S04SS01Q06TB'];
$S04SS01Q07 = $_POST['S04SS01Q07'];
$S04SS01Q07TB = $_POST['S04SS01Q07TB'];
$S04SS01Q08 = $_POST['S04SS01Q08'];
$S04SS01Q08TB = $_POST['S04SS01Q08TB'];

$S05SS01Q01 = $_POST['S05SS01Q01'];
$S05SS01Q02 = $_POST['S05SS01Q02']; 
$S05SS01Q03 = $_POST['S05SS01Q03'];
$S05SS01Q04 = $_POST['S05SS01Q04'];
$S05SS01Q05 = $_POST['S05SS01Q05'];
$S05SS01Q06 = $_POST['S05SS01Q06'];
$S05SS01Q07 = $_POST['S05SS01Q07'];
$S05SS01Q08 = $_POST['S05SS01Q08'];
$S05SS01Q09 = $_POST['S05SS01Q09'];
$S05SS01Q10 = $_POST['S05SS01Q10'];
$S05SS01Q11 = $_POST['S05SS01Q11'];
$S05SS01Q12 = $_POST['S05SS01Q12'];

$S06SS01Q01 = $_POST['S06SS01Q01'];
$S06SS01Q02 = $_POST['S06SS01Q02'];
$S06SS01Q03 = $_POST['S06SS01Q03'];
$S06SS01Q04 = $_POST['S06SS01Q04'];
$S06SS01Q05 = $_POST['S06SS01Q05'];
$S06SS01Q06 = $_POST['S06SS01Q06'];
$S06SS01Q07 = $_POST['S06SS01Q07'];
$S06SS02Q01 = $_POST['S06SS02Q01'];
$S06SS02Q02 = $_POST['S06SS02Q02'];
$S06SS02Q03 = $_POST['S06SS02Q03'];
$S06SS02Q04 = $_POST['S06SS02Q04'];
$S06SS02Q05 = $_POST['S06SS02Q05'];
$S06SS03Q01 = $_POST['S06SS03Q01'];
$S06SS03Q02 = $_POST['S06SS03Q02'];
$S06SS03Q03 = $_POST['S06SS03Q03'];
$S06SS03Q04 = $_POST['S06SS03Q04'];
$S06SS03Q05 = $_POST['S06SS03Q05'];
$S06SS04Q01 = $_POST['S06SS04Q01'];
$S06SS04Q02 = $_POST['S06SS04Q02'];
$S06SS04Q03 = $_POST['S06SS04Q03'];
$S06SS04Q04 = $_POST['S06SS04Q04'];
$S06SS04Q05 = $_POST['S06SS04Q05'];
$S06SS04Q06 = $_POST['S06SS04Q06'];
$S06SS05Q01 = $_POST['S06SS05Q01'];
$S06SS05Q02 = $_POST['S06SS05Q02'];
$S06SS05Q03 = $_POST['S06SS05Q03'];
$S06SS05Q04 = $_POST['S06SS05Q04'];
$S06SS05Q05 = $_POST['S06SS05Q05'];
$S06SS06Q01 = $_POST['S06SS06Q01'];
$S06SS06Q02 = $_POST['S06SS06Q02'];
$S06SS06Q03 = $_POST['S06SS06Q03'];
$S06SS06Q04 = $_POST['S06SS06Q04'];
$S06SS06Q05 = $_POST['S06SS06Q05'];
$S06SS07Q01 = $_POST['S06SS07Q01'];
$S06SS07Q02 = $_POST['S06SS07Q02'];
$S06SS07Q03 = $_POST['S06SS07Q03'];
$S06SS07Q04 = $_POST['S06SS07Q04'];
$S06SS08Q01 = $_POST['S06SS08Q01'];
$S06SS08Q02 = $_POST['S06SS08Q02'];
$S06SS08Q03 = $_POST['S06SS08Q03'];
$S06SS08Q04 = $_POST['S06SS08Q04'];
$S06SS08Q05 = $_POST['S06SS08Q05'];
$S06SS09Q01 = $_POST['S06SS09Q01'];
$S06SS09Q02 = $_POST['S06SS09Q02'];
$S06SS09Q03 = $_POST['S06SS09Q03'];
$S06SS09Q04 = $_POST['S06SS09Q04'];
$S06SS10Q01 = $_POST['S06SS10Q01'];
$S06SS10Q02 = $_POST['S06SS10Q02'];
$S06SS10Q03 = $_POST['S06SS10Q03'];
$S06SS10Q04 = $_POST['S06SS10Q04'];
$S06SS10Q05 = $_POST['S06SS10Q05'];
$S06SS10Q06 = $_POST['S06SS10Q06'];
$S06SS11Q01 = $_POST['S06SS11Q01'];
$S06SS11Q02 = $_POST['S06SS11Q02'];
$S06SS11Q03 = $_POST['S06SS11Q03'];
$S06SS11Q04 = $_POST['S06SS11Q04'];
$S06SS11Q05 = $_POST['S06SS11Q05'];
$S06SS12Q01 = $_POST['S06SS12Q01'];
$S06SS12Q02 = $_POST['S06SS12Q02'];
$S06SS12Q03 = $_POST['S06SS12Q03'];
$S06SS12Q04 = $_POST['S06SS12Q04'];
$S07SS01Q01 = $_POST['S07SS01Q01'];
$S07SS01Q02 = $_POST['S07SS01Q02'];
$S07SS01Q03 = $_POST['S07SS01Q03'];
$S07SS01Q04 = $_POST['S07SS01Q04'];
$S07SS01Q05 = $_POST['S07SS01Q05'];
$S07SS01Q06 = $_POST['S07SS01Q06'];
$S07SS01Q07 = $_POST['S07SS01Q07'];
$S07SS01Q08 = $_POST['S07SS01Q08'];
$S07SS01Q09 = $_POST['S07SS01Q09'];
$S07SS01Q10 = $_POST['S07SS01Q10'];
$S07SS01Q11 = $_POST['S07SS01Q11'];
$S07SS01Q12 = $_POST['S07SS01Q12'];
$S07SS01Q13 = $_POST['S07SS01Q13'];
$S07SS01Q14 = array(); 
if(isset($_POST['S07SS01Q14'])){
    $S07SS01Q14 = implode(",",$_POST['S07SS01Q14']);
};
$S07SS02Q01 = $_POST['S07SS02Q01'];
$S07SS02Q02 = $_POST['S07SS02Q02'];
$S07SS02Q03 = $_POST['S07SS02Q03'];
$S07SS02Q04 = $_POST['S07SS02Q04'];
$S07SS02Q05 = $_POST['S07SS02Q05'];
$S07SS02Q06 = $_POST['S07SS02Q06'];
$S07SS02Q07 = $_POST['S07SS02Q07'];
$S07SS02Q08 = $_POST['S07SS02Q08'];
$S07SS02Q09 = $_POST['S07SS02Q09'];
$S07SS02Q10 = $_POST['S07SS02Q10'];
$S07SS02Q11 = $_POST['S07SS02Q11'];
$S07SS02Q12 = $_POST['S07SS02Q12'];

$sql = 'INSERT INTO Surveys(
    S01SS01Q01,S01SS01Q01TB,S01SS01Q02,S01SS01Q02TB,S01SS01Q03,S01SS01Q03TB,S01SS01Q04,S01SS01Q04TB,S01SS01Q05,S01SS01Q05TB,S01SS01Q06,
    S01SS01Q06TB,S01SS01Q07,S02SS01Q01,S02SS01Q02,S02SS01Q03,S02SS01Q04,S02SS01Q05,S02SS01Q06,S02SS01Q07,S02SS01Q08,S02SS01Q09,S02SS01Q10,
    S02SS01Q11,S02SS01TB,S03SS01Q01,S03SS01Q02,S03SS01Q03,S03SS01Q04,S03SS01Q05,S03SS01Q06,S03SS01Q07,S03SS01Q08,S03SS01Q09,S03SS01Q10,
    S03SS01Q11,S03SS01Q12,S03SS01Q13,S03SS01Q14,S03SS01Q15,S03SS01Q16,S03SS01TB,S04SS01Q01,S04SS01Q01TB,S04SS01Q02,S04SS01Q02TB,S04SS01Q03,
    S04SS01Q03TB,S04SS01Q04,S04SS01Q04TB,S04SS01Q05,S04SS01Q05TB,S04SS01Q06,S04SS01Q06TB,S04SS01Q07,S04SS01Q07TB,S04SS01Q08,S04SS01Q08TB,
    S05SS01Q01,S05SS01Q02,S05SS01Q03,S05SS01Q04,S05SS01Q05,S05SS01Q06,S05SS01Q07,S05SS01Q08,S05SS01Q09,S05SS01Q10,S05SS01Q11,S05SS01Q12,
    S06SS01Q01,S06SS01Q02,S06SS01Q03,S06SS01Q04,S06SS01Q05,S06SS01Q06,S06SS01Q07,S06SS02Q01,S06SS02Q02,S06SS02Q03,S06SS02Q04,S06SS02Q05,
    S06SS03Q01,S06SS03Q02,S06SS03Q03,S06SS03Q04,S06SS03Q05,S06SS04Q01,S06SS04Q02,S06SS04Q03,S06SS04Q04,S06SS04Q05,S06SS04Q06,S06SS05Q01,
    S06SS05Q02,S06SS05Q03,S06SS05Q04,S06SS05Q05,S06SS06Q01,S06SS06Q02,S06SS06Q03,S06SS06Q04,S06SS06Q05,S06SS07Q01,S06SS07Q02,S06SS07Q03,
    S06SS07Q04,S06SS08Q01,S06SS08Q02,S06SS08Q03,S06SS08Q04,S06SS08Q05,S06SS09Q01,S06SS09Q02,S06SS09Q03,S06SS09Q04,S06SS10Q01,S06SS10Q02,
    S06SS10Q03,S06SS10Q04,S06SS10Q05,S06SS10Q06,S06SS11Q01,S06SS11Q02,S06SS11Q03,S06SS11Q04,S06SS11Q05,S06SS12Q01,S06SS12Q02,S06SS12Q03,
    S06SS12Q04,S07SS01Q01,S07SS01Q02,S07SS01Q03,S07SS01Q04,S07SS01Q05,S07SS01Q06,S07SS01Q07,S07SS01Q08,S07SS01Q09,S07SS01Q10,S07SS01Q11,
    S07SS01Q12,S07SS01Q13,S07SS01Q14,S07SS02Q01,S07SS02Q02,S07SS02Q03,S07SS02Q04,S07SS02Q05,S07SS02Q06,S07SS02Q07,S07SS02Q08,S07SS02Q09,
    S07SS02Q10,S07SS02Q11,S07SS02Q12
    ) VALUES (
    ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, 
    ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, 
    ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, 
    ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, 
    ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?
    )';

$ssqls = mysqli_prepare($link,$sql);

if($ssqls){
echo "complete if";
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($ssqls,"siiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiii
                                   iiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiii
                                   iiiiiisisssiiiiiiiisiiiiiiiiiiii",
                                   $username, $tenureyears, $tenuremonths, $gender, $marital, $S01SS01Q01, $S01SS01Q01TB, $S01SS01Q02, 
                                   $S01SS01Q02TB, $S01SS01Q03, $S01SS01Q03TB, $S01SS01Q04, $S01SS01Q04TB, $S01SS01Q05, $S01SS01Q05TB, 
                                   $S01SS01Q06, $S01SS01Q06TB, $S01SS01Q07, $S02SS01Q01, $S02SS01Q02, $S02SS01Q03, $S02SS01Q04, $S02SS01Q05, 
                                   $S02SS01Q06, $S02SS01Q07, $S02SS01Q08, $S02SS01Q09, $S02SS01Q10, $S02SS01Q11, $S02SS01TB, $S03SS01Q01, 
                                   $S03SS01Q02, $S03SS01Q03, $S03SS01Q04, $S03SS01Q05, $S03SS01Q06, $S03SS01Q07, $S03SS01Q08, $S03SS01Q09, 
                                   $S03SS01Q10, $S03SS01Q11, $S03SS01Q12, $S03SS01Q13, $S03SS01Q14, $S03SS01Q15, $S03SS01Q16, $S03SS01TB, 
                                   $S04SS01Q01, $S04SS01Q01TB, $S04SS01Q02, $S04SS01Q02TB, $S04SS01Q03, $S04SS01Q03TB, $S04SS01Q04, 
                                   $S04SS01Q04TB, $S04SS01Q05, $S04SS01Q05TB, $S04SS01Q06, $S04SS01Q06TB, $S04SS01Q07, $S04SS01Q07TB, 
                                   $S04SS01Q08, $S04SS01Q08TB, $S05SS01Q01, $S05SS01Q02, $S05SS01Q03, $S05SS01Q04, $S05SS01Q05, $S05SS01Q06, 
                                   $S05SS01Q07, $S05SS01Q08, $S05SS01Q09, $S05SS01Q10, $S05SS01Q11, $S05SS01Q12, $S06SS01Q01, $S06SS01Q02, 
                                   $S06SS01Q03, $S06SS01Q04, $S06SS01Q05, $S06SS01Q06, $S06SS01Q07, $S06SS02Q01, $S06SS02Q02, $S06SS02Q03, 
                                   $S06SS02Q04, $S06SS02Q05, $S06SS03Q01, $S06SS03Q02, $S06SS03Q03, $S06SS03Q04, $S06SS03Q05, $S06SS04Q01, 
                                   $S06SS04Q02, $S06SS04Q03, $S06SS04Q04, $S06SS04Q05, $S06SS04Q06, $S06SS05Q01, $S06SS05Q02, $S06SS05Q03, 
                                   $S06SS05Q04, $S06SS05Q05, $S06SS06Q01, $S06SS06Q02, $S06SS06Q03, $S06SS06Q04, $S06SS06Q05, $S06SS07Q01, 
                                   $S06SS07Q02, $S06SS07Q03, $S06SS07Q04, $S06SS08Q01, $S06SS08Q02, $S06SS08Q03, $S06SS08Q04, $S06SS08Q05, 
                                   $S06SS09Q01, $S06SS09Q02, $S06SS09Q03, $S06SS09Q04, $S06SS10Q01, $S06SS10Q02, $S06SS10Q03, $S06SS10Q04, 
                                   $S06SS10Q05, $S06SS10Q06, $S06SS11Q01, $S06SS11Q02, $S06SS11Q03, $S06SS11Q04, $S06SS11Q05, $S06SS12Q01, 
                                   $S06SS12Q02, $S06SS12Q03, $S06SS12Q04, $S07SS01Q01, $S07SS01Q02, $S07SS01Q03, $S07SS01Q04, $S07SS01Q05, 
                                   $S07SS01Q06, $S07SS01Q07, $S07SS01Q08, $S07SS01Q09, $S07SS01Q10, $S07SS01Q11, $S07SS01Q12, $S07SS01Q13, 
                                   $S07SS01Q14, $S07SS02Q01, $S07SS02Q02, $S07SS02Q03, $S07SS02Q04, $S07SS02Q05, $S07SS02Q06, $S07SS02Q07, 
                                   $S07SS02Q08, $S07SS02Q09, $S07SS02Q10, $S07SS02Q11, $S07SS02Q12);

    mysqli_stmt_execute($ssqls); 
    mysqli_stmt_fetch($ssqls);

    }else{printf('errno: %d, error: %s', $ssqls->errno, $ssqls->error);}
```

Comment: Your `else` block is the inverse of `if ($ssqls)`. You won't get anything meaningful off `$ssqls` there as it's probably `false`. Try `$link->error` instead

Comment: I highly recommend executing this at the top of your script (at least while developing) ~ `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 'On'); mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);`